# In Vue3's compositional API, how can I v-bind a dynamic group of props to a child component and not lose reactivity?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-props, vue-reactivity

The context is that I have a `Button` component and a `SquareButton` component that wraps it as a higher order component. The `SquareButton` takes the same props as `Button`, but includes an extra prop needed for a calculation. All the rest of the props should be passed down to the `Button`. Like so (to simplify):

**Button.vue**

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
export interface ButtonProps {
  width?: number
  height?: number
  // Plus a bunch more. These all need to make it onto the button.
}

// Already I am losing reactivity by destructuring here.
// However, I need access to `rest`.
const { width, height, ...rest } = withDefaults(defineProps<ButtonProps>(), {
  width: 150,
  height: 75,
})
</script>

<template>
  <button v-bind="rest">
    <slot />
  <button>
</template>

<style scoped>
  button {
    display: flex;
    width: v-bind(width + "px");
    height: v-bind(height + "px");
  } 
</style>
```

**SquareButton.vue**

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import Button from "./Button.vue"

export interface SquareButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  size?: number
}

const { size, ...rest } = withDefaults(
  defineProps<SquareButtonProps>(),
  {
    size: 30,
  }
)
</script>

<template>
  <Button :width="size" :height="size" v-bind="rest">
    <slot />
  </Button>
</template>
```

So the first problem is that I don't want to lose reactivity. If one of these props changes, I need everything to update. This means destructuring is bad. Various solutions to this problem recommend using the `toRefs` function. So let's refactor to use this technique:

**SquareButton.vue refactored**

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import Button from "./Button.vue"
import { toRefs } from "vue"

export interface SquareButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  size?: number
}

const props = withDefaults(
  defineProps<SquareButtonProps>(),
  {
    size: 30,
  }
)

const { size, ...rest } = toRefs(props)
</script>

<template>
  <!-- Error -->
  <Button :width="size" :height="size" v-bind="rest">
    <slot />
  </Button>
</template>
```

The error I get here occurs because `Button` is expecting props with normal value types like strings and numbers. But instead, I'm now giving it reactive objects, and it is rightly angry.

So how in the world am I supposed to forward these props down without losing reactivity? The reactivity is important because, when props change, I need my components to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remembering  never to destructur the props, you can directly use it in template.
2. v-bind will automatically add to the root tag of the components,this called Attribute Inheritance ,[see the document](https://cn.vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html)

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import Button from "./Button.vue"
export interface SquareButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  size?: number
}
const props = withDefaults(
  defineProps<SquareButtonProps>(),
  {
    size: 30,
  }
)
</script>
<template>
  <Button :width="size" :height="size">
    <slot />
  </Button>
</template>
```